# Remove white spaces and punctuations (except parentheses) from starting and end of one column in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, str-replace

Given a small dataset as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':[' a..b?!??', '%hgh&12','abc123(bj)!!!', '$$$1234（gz）']})
df
```

Out:

```
            text
0       a..b?!??
1        %hgh&12
2  abc123(bj)!!!
3    $$$1234（gz）
```

I need to remove white spaces, punctuations from **left and right sides**  of `text` column, **except english and chinese parentheses**.

The expected result:

```
            text
0           a..b
1         hgh&12
2     abc123(bj)
3       1234（gz）
```

How could I do that in Python?

My code:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')
```

Out:

```
0          ab
1       hgh12
2    abc123bj
3      1234gz
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) with all values from `string.punctuation` without parentheses and also is added  :

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.strip('!"#$%&*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ' + "'")
print (df)
         text
0        a..b
1      hgh&12
2  abc123(bj)
3    1234（gz）
```

Dynamic solution should be:

```
import string
rem = ['(',')']
add = [' ']
a = set(list(string.punctuation) + add) - set(rem)
    
df['text'] = df['text'].str.strip(''.join(a))
```

Comment: Thanks, do we need enumerate all the possible punctuations?

Comment: @ahbon - there is problem need remove `()` and add `' '`, so it is reason for custom `punctuation`, there is added `""` for select `'` value, it is used for start and end of string for first long string

Comment: Does your dynamic solution adapt to chinese punctuations?

Comment: @ahbon - I hope so, add values for add and for remove in lists `add` and `rem`. I think chinese values are not in `string.punctuation`, so if need remove them add values to list `add`

Answer (score 1):

Use the "strip" function. Small example below

```py
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())
```

Comment: yes, I didnt read the question thoroughly - your answer solves it anyway, so all good